# Как получить QuerySet по списку возможных параметров?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-orm

Как реализовать конструкцию изображенную ниже?

```
list_of_foreign_keys = [foreign_key1, foreign_key2, ...]
Model.objects.filter(date__range=[start_date, end_date],
                     # ... some parameters
                     foreign_key = list_of_foreign_keys,)
```

`list_of_foreign_keys` - перечисление возможных ключей.

Comment: Распишите подробней. Из вопроса ничего не понятно.

Comment: Есть модель с ForeignKey. Необходимо получить выборку по списку ключевых объектов. Т.е.: для каждого ключа в list_of_foreign_keys

Comment: В чем условие списка list_of_foreign_keys? ForeignKey указывают ссылки на другие модели или наоборот ссылаются на вашу модель?

Comment: list_of_foreign_keys - QuerySet.
ForeignKey - указывает на MPTT модель из которой получаю QuerySet методом .get_descendant()

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то вам нужно:

```
foreign_key__in=list_of_foreign_keys
```

Comment: ДА! Спасибо. Это то что нужно.